# Error de archivo cerrado al guardar imágenes mayores a 45KB ASP.Net - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post, web.config

Necesito almacenar imágenes en una tabla en sql server a través de un stored procedure. Tengo el siguiente código en el cual guardo las imágenes en una variable de sesión (para mantenerlas luego del postback) y luego las paso a una lista para los casos donde necesite guardar más de una imagen. Recorro la lista y guardo una a una las imágenes.

```
public void GuardarImagen(int idCliente) 
    {
        NegClientes nc = new NegClientes();
        List<HttpPostedFile> fotos = (List<HttpPostedFile>)Session["Fotos"];

        foreach (HttpPostedFile item in fotos)
        {
            if (item.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(item.InputStream))
                {
                    byte[] image = reader.ReadBytes(item.ContentLength);
                    nc.InsertarImagenCliente(idCliente, image, item.ContentType);

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta acá me funciona perfecto, las imágenes se guardan pero solo puedo guardar archivos de hasta 45KB.
Vi en varios lugares que por defecto IIS permite almacenar archivos hasta 4Mb y que se puede configurar desde el tag `httpRuntime` en el web.config

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="500000" requestLengthDiskThreshold="500000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" executionTimeout="90"/>
```

Acá las propiedades que permiten modificar el tamaño de los archivos a guardar son `maxRequestLength` y `requestLengthDiskThreshold` pero sigue sin aceptar archivos mayores a 45Kb.
Cuando intento almacenar la imagen en una array de bytes

> byte[] image = reader.ReadBytes(item.ContentLength);

Me lanza el error:

> "No se puede obtener acceso a un archivo cerrado."

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
No es problema del tamaño del archivo ya que modifiqué desde el CodeBehind el tamaño del `MaxRequestLength` y el `RequestLengthDiskThreshold` pero sigue lanzando el mismo error.

```
        System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection rs = new HttpRuntimeSection();
        rs.MaxRequestLength = 200000;
        rs.RequestLengthDiskThreshold = 200000;
```

Lo que llego a entender es que debo abrir o "reabrir" el `item.InputStream` pero no logro hacerlo.

Comment: no tienes que hacer reader.open para poder iniciar la transferencia?, yo intentaria cambiar el binaryreader por un filestream

Answer (score 0):

Hola prueba a modificar así tu código para rellenar el array a insertar en tu bbdd

```
byte[] image = new byte[item.ContentLength]; // establecer array bytes

item.InputStream.Read(image,0,item.ContentLength); // rellenar el array bytes
```